# Upload to another domain (same server)

Tags: php, upload

I put permission 777 on the other server I can send the file, but when access the file shows internal server error 500

This is related to the permission of owner I think, someone knows how I can solve? Obs: I already tended all types of file permissions and all that let me send the file shows the error 500

```html
$dir_https_braip = "/home/braip/public_html/https/";enter code here
$dir_https_way = "/home/waycash/public_html/dir/https/";
$dir_https_pega = "/home/pegatudo/public_html/dir/https/";

if(!copy($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], $dir_https_braip . $nome)){
 
  die('erro');
}
```

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: var_dump(is_writable($dir_https_braip));